# Liskov Substitution Principle Edge Case

Tags: object-oriented-design, solid, liskov-substitution, ooad

I thought I understood Liskov Substitution Principle but then I thought of a case and I wanted to ask the community here if I get it right.

So I read somewhere to check if we have violated Liskov or not, amongst other things, we also need to inspect the client code which is using the classes in question.

So I have an example below, please help me understand if I have broken LSP.

```java
class A {

 void doWork(){
    // superclass specific implementation
 }

 void doSomeOtherWork(){
    // superclass specific implementation
 }
}

class B extends A {
 void doWork(){
    // subclass specific implementation
 }
}
```

**Client Code**
*NOTE: Let's assume that the client code is fixed, and cannot be modified.*

```java
class WorkProcessor{

 void process(A a){
   a.doWork();
 }
}
```

Now in general it is true that superclass **A** has a behavior i.e **doSomeOtherWork()** which is not relevant to subclass **B**, so ideally this would violate LSP as subtype cannot be replaced by supertype.

But looking at the client code, and assuming hypothetically that the client code is fixed, we can see that **a.doWork()** is getting invoked and it will work even if we pass an instance of subclass **B**.

> So in the context of the client, we do not violate the LSP.

Am I right in making the above statement?

Comment: B just uses the inherited doSomeOtherWork, how does that break LSP? On the other hand you have broken the ISP because the WorkProcessor is still exposed to a method it doesn't care about.

Comment: `A has a behaviour i.e doSomeOtherWork() which is not relevant to subclass B, so ideally this would violate LSP` Why. In what way does it break LSP? To me is just a flawed abstraction, but that's it.

Comment: @Laiv If WorkProcessor was using a.doSomeOtherWork() then it does violate LSP.
Because B although inheriting doSomeOtherWork() but let us say it is not relevant to it.

But since WorkProcessor is calling a.doWork() then it does not violate LSP.

So is LSP depends on the context in which the client code is using the classes in question.

Comment: LSP doesn't depend on the context (caller or callee). The example is quite meaningless and poor for us to explain (easily) why B is not breaking LSP. I would edit the question and add "what do I think LSP means" and why I think B break it. Maybe the issue is in the interpretation you give to LSP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A class doesn't violate LSP by merely having an extra method. The behaviors that LSP talks about are not methods, but rules and relationsips and constraints that the class is meant to follow/enforce as you poke it in different ways (the rules governing the client-observable transformations as you call various methods on the type). E.g., in the (in)famous Rectangle-Square example, the behaviors are not "I can set width" and "I can set height", the relevant behavior (the contract, what the type promises to be the case) is "I can set width and height independently". This requirement, for the purposes of that example, is not inherent in the interface of the Rectangle (although it might be natural to assume that it holds), this is imposed externally by the developer - and this is what gets broken in the Square "subtype" (which then makes it not be a real subtype by LSP definition).

**That said**, you are right in that a that class that derives or implements something else (or, in case of structural typing, has a structure compatible with something else) can violate LSP in one context, but not in a different one.

But it doesn't matter so much what the client code is *doing*, what matters is what it *expects* of the type it consumes. That is, it's more about the *behavioral contract* of the type it makes use of.

Now, in a statically typed language, you'd associate that contract with a *role-based* interface. That is, instead of:

```java
class B extends A {
 void doWork(){
    // subclass specific implementation
 }
}
```

you'd have something like this

```java
interface Worker {
  void doWork()
}

class B extends A implements Worker {
 void doWork(){
    // subclass specific implementation
 }
}


class WorkProcessor{

 void process(Worker a){
   a.doWork();
 }
}
```

But in a dynamically typed / duck typed language, there wouldn't be such an interface. You'd have to look at what's expected of that parameter in that context - and you'll find that in the *documentation*. (Most programming languages, loosely or strongly typed, are not capable of fully expressing those expectations in the interfaces/classes themselves).

E.g. look at the sort() in JavaScript; it can take in a `compareFn` - something that tells it how to compare two values, that it can then use to sort an array of values it otherwise doesn't understand.

Now, as Laiv pointed out in a comment, it's hard to meaningfully break LSP for a general-purpose sort, but suppose you were writing your own library that passed a `compareFn` to a sort it used internally, and required that `compareFn` was such that it established what mathematicians would call a *total order* on the elements you were iterating over - that is, imagine your code relies on the fact that there is a sensible way to order the elements, otherwise, it might return unpredictable results, or even throw. Clients of your library would supply a `compareFn` to it, but what they pass in must satisfy certain behavioral requirements.

The signature of `compareFn` tells you that it takes two values, and returns a number: `(a, b) -> Number`. A signature is like a formal type of the function.

But the *behavior* of the function, the thing that fully defines a type in the LSP sense, would be specified like so.

First, it would have to follow this specification from the documentation of the [sort() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

| compareFn(a, b) return value | sort order |
| --- | --- |
| > 0 | sort a after b |
| < 0 | sort a before b |
| === 0 | keep original order of a and b |

Second, because of your ordering requirements, the implementation would have to make sure that these things are true:

- `compare(a, a)` must return `0`
- If `compare(a, b) < 0` and `compare(b, c) < 0`, then compare(a, c) must also return a value `< 0`.
- If `compare(a, b) === 0`, then `compare(b, a)` should also be `=== 0`
- `compare(a, b) < 0` and `compare(b, a) < 0` cannot both be true

Note that clients can relatively easily supply a function that violates any of these (perhaps in a non-obvious way - maybe they are doing some calculation to determine the order, or pulling values from some precomputed table), and if they do, this will break the expectations of your code.

*Aside*: the term "behavior" is really mathematical/academic jargon - it refers to these rules/constraints/invariants that govern what happens when you do something to an object (when you pass a certain set of parameters, or as it transitions from one state to another, etc).

So, the function supplied by the clients of your library needs to respect these constraints if they want to make us of it. If they don't do this, they are either doing something hack-y on purpose (accepting the risk that their code might break if internal details of the library change), or the implementation of the comparison function they provided is breaking LSP unintentionally, and they might end up with a bug or undefined behavior.

This example just showcases a behavioral specification of a single function, but you can imagine that you can do this for classes, and more importantly, for interfaces - and it doesn't have to be this abstract or mathy in nature.

The problem with your example is that it doesn't have any nontrivial client-observable behavior in the above sense - it's just a fire and forget function call.

Comment: Hm. I'm struggling with the idea of _strategy pattern_ breaking LSP. How a function breaks _sort()_? If the given function alters any of the components so that the next comparison gives a different and unexpected result, doesn't break LSP. It's a weird sort indeed, but still a sort. Isn't? I'm also confused about breaking LSP in non-typed languages. If there's no type, then there's no LSP to break. There's no type replacing in the first place. Is LSP also relevant, lets say, in functional programming? Or in non-OO paradigms?

Comment: @Laiv I guess a general purpose array sort is somewhat of a bad example, but I needed something simple that had a documented behavior. I might replace it with something better later. But, suppose you have your own domain-specific sorter function that takes in a compareFn, and requires all this, and in addition requires compareFn to produce a well-defined order on the element type - because your code *relies on that property*. So, no rock-paper-scissors loops, a < b and b < c has to imply a < c, etc. You'll break your library if you supply a compareFn that doesn't do that.

Comment: Also, it might not break sort itself, but it might break your code that calls sort and makes assumptions about what it returns.

Comment: @Laiv - I used the example from the comments in the answer, hopefully, that gets the point across a little better. But the difficulty you pointed out has to do with how general the sort/compareFn combination is, not with the strategy pattern. You can absolutely break LSP in the strategy pattern - it's just a matter of what the contract of the strategy is.

Comment: And yet I don't think a weird `compareFn` can break sort.  You can implement different sorting strategies without breaking LSP. If the wrong order of items breaks the code that has nothing to do with LSP (IMO). It would be like implementing a wrong loop. The sort works and does what it's expected: _"given a set of elements, they are sorted according to the logic defined in `F`"_. If you make `sort` parametrizable with a strategy pattern, you can not blame the implementation of the strategy if your code stops working. If a specific order is required, then you don't implement a strategy pattern.

Answer (score 1):

> Now in general it is true that superclass A has a behavior i.e doSomeOtherWork() which is not relevant to subclass B, so ideally this would violate LSP as subtype cannot be replaced by supertype

This is more an issue of incorrect inheritance than anything to do with LSP.

LSP says, basically, that any code that works fine with the parent class should also work fine with a child class, that the code calling it shouldn't care.

So if you have a `Mammal` class that has method `milkOffspring` then any child class of `Mammal`, such as `Dog` or `Cow` should work just fine where ever you might put `Mammal` in. It should never break because code that expected to get a `Mammal` class instead got a `Dog` class (it get a bit more formal than that, but that is the gist of it)

In your example though if `A` has behaviour that is not relevant to `B` then `B` is *not* a type of `A`

It would be like saying there is a `fly()` method in `Mammal` that only some child classes care about, but `Dog` doesn't care about. That is broken inheritance.

As others have pointed out `B` gets `doSomeOtherWork` via inheritance but you seem to be saying that `doSomeOtherWork` is not a method `B` cares about

In which case your inheritance tree is incorrect and you probably want to switch over to composition or something.

So there is a more general principle you are violating here, which isn't LSP. It is that you are putting specialization into parent classes, specialization that some child classes don't care about.